# GAE - Retrieving Database content via commandline

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have the following GQL database model:

```
class Post(db.Model):
subject = db.StringProperty(required = True)
content = db.TextProperty(required = True)
created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

And this is the `POST request` used to store content to the database

```
def post(self):
    subject = self.request.get('subject')
    content = self.request.get('content')

    if subject and content:
        a = Post(subject = subject, content = content)
        a.put()

        self.redirect("/")
    else:
        error = "subject and content can neither be empty"
        self.Render_NewPost(subject, content, error)
```

If I `POST` content to the database it works alright since i don't get the error. However I don't get the contents to show on the page it is suppose to show.

I'm interested in knowing the command line instruction I can use to check the database to be sure if the contents been `post`ed are actually in the database or not so I can know where to figure out the problem of the content not showing on my Homepage as I hoped.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wait 30 seconds and refresh the page `/`.  You may be running into the issue of "eventual consistency", where the data will "eventually" be put into the physical datastore you've queried, but may not be there yet.